# Foreign Keys not lining up in raw SQL and FLASK SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have somewhat of a general question, also curious about best practices. I have a model in SQL which looks as so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.volunteer_report
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  volunteer_id integer NOT NULL,
  client_id integer NOT NULL,
  user_need_id integer NOT NULL,
  report character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  report_category character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  created_by text,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_by text,
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT fk_volunteer_report_volunteer FOREIGN KEY (volunteer_id)
      REFERENCES public.user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_volunteer_report_client FOREIGN KEY (client_id)
      REFERENCES public.user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_volunteer_report_client_need FOREIGN KEY (user_need_id)
      REFERENCES public.user_need (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Both FK's make a reference to the **user** PK.

**MY FLASK APP**

```
class VolunteerReport(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'volunteer_report'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    volunteer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('volunteer_client.volunteer_id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='RESTRICT'))
    client_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('volunteer_client.client_id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='RESTRICT'))
    user_need_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user_need.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='RESTRICT'))
    report = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    report_category = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
```

The FK references are different here. referencing **volunteer_client** table instead of **user** table, but the int FK value that gets stored is the same.

Is this expected to work and perform fine, or should the table references be exactly identical?

Comment: Is `volunteer_client.volunteer_id` a FK to `user.id`, and the same for `volunteer_client.client_id`? It looks like SQLAlchemy is depending on this transitive relationship.

Comment: @Barmar yes they are FK in another table that reference ```user.id``` PK